# How to run inference using pre-trained Tensorflow model from their Github and CheckPoint file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to collect text embeddings from the model in this github

https://github.com/dmis-lab/biobert

Under installation, all it says is

> To use BioBERT, we need pre-trained weights of BioBERT, which you can
>   download from Naver GitHub repository for BioBERT pre-trained weights.
>   Make sure to specify the versions of pre-trained weights used in your
>   works. Also, note that this repository is based on the BERT repository
>   by Google.
>
> All the fine-tuning experiments were conducted on a single TITAN Xp
>   GPU machine which has 12GB of RAM. The code was tested with Python2
>   and Python3 (We used Python2 for experiments). You might want to
>   install java to use official evaluation script of BioASQ. See
>   requirements.txt for other details.

I can download their checkpoint file and load it using something like

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:

   saver.restore(session, 'BioBert.ckpt' )
```

And install their github using something like

```
!test -d bioBert_repo|| git clone https://github.com/dmis-lab/biobert bioBert_repo
```

But how do I get the embedding from a text input. The instructions say it's based on BERT, but for BERT all we have to do is import the tf.hub model

```
bert_module = hub.Module(
 "https://tfhub.dev/google/bert_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1",
 trainable=False)
```

then
put the tokenized sentence into that

```
bert_embedding= bert_module(inputs=tokenized_sentence, signature="tokens", as_dict=True)[
       "pooled_output"
   ]
```

I'm guessing there's a similar method where I can install the github and load the weights but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Any progress with this problem?

Comment: I believe I solved it but have since switched to huggingface so I don't remember the exact solution

Answer (score 0):

You should see example from extract_features.py.
I suppose that BIOBert don't use tf.hub.